# Word for a person who is attracted to the depth of a character or one who likes deep conversation

Tags: single-word-requests, personality

What do we call a person, who loves to engage in deep conversations; who is not into silly talks. A person who is attracted to the soul of another person, the depth of his/her character. A person who has so much into his/her mind and thoughts.

In simple words, I would say, **what do we call a person, who has a lot of intensity to his character,thoughts and talks**

note: Since, the exact requirement of question being confusing for many, i would like to add a character from a movie as an example.

I hope many of you would have seen the film, ***

> Into The Wild(2017)

***, American biographical drama survival film written and directed by Sean Penn. It is an adaptation of Jon Krakauer's 1996 non-fiction book of the same name, based on the travels of Christopher McCandless.

The character of **Christopher McCandles** portrayed by **Emile Hirsch** is the one I would pick as an example.

Though the character is of a traveller, whom we would call as a wanderlust.But, I think there is more in his character. The vibe, the intensity that character gives out is much more than that of a wanderlust.

So, In simple terms, what is that beautiful term, with which we can address such a person.

Comment: Are you talking about a deep person or someone who likes deep people? Please clarify.

Comment: yes, someone who is a deep person and is attracted towards people with depth. it is kinda of both, i guess

Comment: You mean a [sapiosexual](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sapiosexual&oq=sapiosexual&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2423j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: sapiosexual is finding intelligence attractive, right? but, what i think or understand is, intelligence and depth are different. there are intelligent people with no depth, right. something more than sapiosexual.

Comment: I get your point, but still, I'm afraid you'll have to define depth here. If not intellect, what's your yardstick? Moral fiber? Intensity? Unpredictability?

Comment: among all these i would pick intensity. intensity in character, in thoughts and in talks.

Comment: Okay. I would suggest you edit your question to reflect this, and get rid of the potentially misleading emphasis.

Comment: okay, i'll do that. thank you anyways, i expect an answer from you.

Comment: "Depth" of character is highly subjective. What more can you add to narrow down the answers?

Answer (score 6):

**A profound person**

is someone who would fit your definition.

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/profound)

> adjective: 
>   A profound idea, work, or **person** shows **great intellectual
>   depth and understanding**.

Comment: these all words tend to address some attributes of such a character, but not completely. I accept all answers but none satisfies me. I m sorry for that. but thank you al.

Answer (score 3):

I usually call such a person [**serious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serious?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld). From Webster:

> #### Serious
>
> 1. Thoughtful or subdued in appearance or manner :  sober (a quiet, serious girl)
> 2. a : Requiring much thought or work (serious study)
>
>    b :  Of or relating to a matter of importance (a serious play)
> 3. a : Not joking or trifling : being in earnest (a serious question)
>
>    b : Archaic : pious
>
>    c : Deeply interested : devoted (a serious musician)

Comment: This site is looking for more detailed answers. Please check out [How To Answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) if you are unsure what helps make an answer good and detailed.

Answer (score 3):

As a noun, [***intellectual***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intellectual) fits your description very well.

> 6. a person of superior intellect.
> 7. a person who places a high value on or pursues things of interest to the intellect or the more complex forms and fields of knowledge, as aesthetic or philosophical matters, especially on an abstract and general level.

Examples:

> He's an intellectual. He cannot have a casual conversation, but insists that every encounter is a meaningful one that focuses on complex topics.
>
> Two intellectuals can talk for many hours, spanning many topics, only to conclude that neither of them can pronounce anything with certainty.

Some decent synonyms include:

- Academic
- Learned person
- Egghead

Answer (score 2):

How about **thinker**?

OD:

[**thinker**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinker): A person who thinks deeply and seriously; a person with highly developed intellectual powers, especially one whose profession involves intellectual activity

Answer (score 1):

**a philosopher** comes to mind.

> - a person who offers views or theories on profound questions in ethics, metaphysics, logic, and other related fields.  [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/philosopher)
> - A philosopher is someone who practices philosophy, which involves rational inquiry into areas that are outside of either theology or science.  - [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher)

Comment: philosopher sounds some what more formal, official. Think about a person who is calm and composed, who is not worried about this modern life demands. Who is not into this competitive world, who has a different opinion of his own, to which we all agree, but we are unable to pursue or support practically. I m having such a character in my mind.

pardon me, if i m confusing you all.

Comment: I wish if that word had the beauty of that character, that intensity he posses. I wish.

Comment: @SHAHAL NS  A philosopher certainly enjoys talking about "deep subjects"

Comment: yes, i know that. but somewhere i m confused, whether to accept the term philosopher. I strongly believe there can be a better word. hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

The term [**old soul**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=old%20soul) can be used to describe a person who is contemplative, thoughtful, and displays wisdom, maturity and intelligence, regardless of their physical age. It's often used to describe someone who has a philosophical outlook on life, and displays insights that many others may not, and in many cases is used to refer to a young person who seems to display the maturity of an older person.

The term is often used in a more literal sense to mean a person whose soul has existed for a long time, or even has been reincarnated multiple times, which is believed to be the source of their wisdom and insight. Web searches will return a lot of references to this meaning, but I am using it here in the sense of a person who displays characteristics which would be associated with an experienced and thoughtful person.

Comment: I suspect an old soul wouldn't ratchet-up the intensity just because they encountered someone with an intellect deeper than a small soap dish. There is an implication of grace in the term, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

This person is often called **real**.

*"He's real, you know. Some guys they just take one look and they, well, you know. But James cares about what I actually have to say and the things I've gone through and he's not going to judge me."*

: genuine [Merriam Webster's]

I like *genuine*, too, but I think the OP's question works better with *real*.

Answer (score 0):

From OD:

Erudite (adj.)

Having or showing great knowledge or learning:
‘Ken could turn any conversation into an erudite discussion’
‘she was very erudite’

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a **dilettante**. Passionate about the finer things, not interested in small talk. However, as it has been pointed out, they are not above affectation.

Comment: A dilettante likes many things _superficially_, so mostly the opposite of deep things.

Comment: @Mitch, I don't think someone who could claim to be "attracted to the soul of another person" is dealing with serious thoughts. You are right that a dilettante can have superficial interests, but I thought they could meet the OP's requirement for "intensity", however superficial or affected they might be. I edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: The primary meaning of dilettante is multiple _superficial_ interests, familiar with many things with little depth. Whatever the secondary implications (I'm not sure that 'not interested in small talk' is an actual implication), superficiality is entirely at odds with the OP request for a word showing depth or intensity.